# disconnect dialup from php

Tags: php, networking

I have an application for a client and it asks me to retry the internet connection in order for the host to acquire a new ip. Problem is, I can't find a way to disconnect and connect back again with the internet connection using php. Any ideas?

Comment: Please describe in more detail how this is set up. What kind of an application for a client do you have? Where is PHP running, on the client or on the server? Who is connected through dialup and where? What operating systems are the client and the server running?

Comment: windows xp, php is installed on the same machine so he's the server and client. Application is a web bot which posts some ads but since he doesn't want to use proxies, I need to retry his internet connection in order to acquire a new ip

Comment: Two things: first off, PHP probably isn't a great language to be doing Windows system calls from. I would write scripts to do that in something like VB and call them via backticks. Second, if this is for a spam engine, then we're under absolutely no obligation to help. Spam engines violate a number of federal laws in the US and the EU, so providing assistance would be both illegal and ethically improper.

Comment: c'mon man. I asked for programming help. Nobody said you're under obligation. Why does every one correlates bot with spam huh? Stop judging people for what they're paid to do and try to keep it on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to have the PHP installed on his machine execute an external program that could bounce the modem. A quick Google search found [this](http://www.techstroke.com/connect-disconnect-pppoe-or-dial-up-using-command-line-or-batch-scripting.html). That or something similar might come in handy.

Of course, the Apache account will have to have sufficient permissions to be able to affect the modem and execute the program.